# Is cordova fast enough with android scrolling, menu and transition?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Me and my friend creating a location based app. We need to make the app smooth. We're using crosswalk, Intel app framework and Cordova. Will support android 4.0 and up. Can we rely on Cordova entirely, or do we need to implement the "Cordova webview inside native app method?"

Comment: I guess it depends on your specifications. I just build an app with the intel app framework and it runs smoothly. I discovered that if you load a page with a list containing many items it will take some time to load them.

Comment: So i gotta skip the -li- and -ul- tags?

Comment: no, just don't put hundreds of -li- inside the -ul-, load 20-30 and when the user reach the top-bottom, load more and destroy others.

Comment: and if you really want to load that many, you can load them with display: none and make them visible with a timeout or using infinite scroll

Comment: Im just worrying if the ui will be smooth enough, so as not to give the user the feeling 'hey! Somethings wrong with this app'

Comment: Switched to ionic framework. The community is more responsive and helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Use these css property in scrollable events...